# Can't make rgba() background-colour on select element work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome Version 16.0.912.75 m running on Vista.

I'm trying to apply an rgba background colour to a disabled select element, with the opacity at 0.2.

It works fine in Firefox and Opera, but Chrome ignores the opacity, and just shows flat colour.
I've already tried adding -webkit-appearance: none. This fixes the alpha value, but removes the button part fo the select element from view.

Does anyone know how how to have a background with an alpha value, and not hide the button part of select?

http://jsfiddle.net/EMSmZ/9/ <== I've edited this to confirm that rgba is otherwise working for background colour, but not for select. The two boxes have different background transparencies in Chrome, but the selects don't.

---

Still nothing, submitted a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110437

Comment: strange, just tried this and i seem to be getting the opacity just fine in both browsers Chrome: 16.0.912.75 as well...

Comment: Strange is right. Which OS are you using, please?

Comment: I'm using OSX. i hope we're talking about the same thing: in this fiddle i see the body's red background behind the buttons in both chrome and firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/N3VMU/

Comment: As you see it, does the second select element have a flat black background or a transparent grey one?

Comment: That's how it should look. Still black for me, and a colleague with the same version. Weird stuff. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: **Google Chrome** : *16.0.912.63* **OS** : *Windows* **WebKit** : *535.7*  I experience the same flat background effect... good catch.

Comment: Keep in mind that browsers often use the OS provided controls for forms, that means they are limited the abilities that the OS provides. So if the OS select element doesn't support alpha-background (which is quite likely IMHO) then the browser won't either. Generally it's a bad idea "needing" to format form controls a specific way consistently over browsers and OSes, especially if you what to use such an unusual styling. My suggestion would be be to reconsider this and avoid styling form controls in such an unusual way. Or use a library to replace the element with a "JavaScript widget".

Comment: I don't think that's it. Safari, Opera and Firefox can all handle it, and IE has a different way of showing them.
I know my use of css is unusual, but the css itself is standard, and it's only Chrome that has the problem.
I can't use jQuery UI or any equivalent library, there are too many form elements to process that way.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to break this to you, but styling form elements with CSS is just a bag of hurt. There's a reason everyone uses Javascript replacement techniques to change the look and feel of form elements.. (except text and text area essentially)

Comment: It's ok, I found a solution in the end. Changed jobs :P I agree, javascript replacements are the sane way to do it. The project I was working on was comically overloaded with AJAX though, and adding more DOM changes was like playing Buckaroo.

Answer (score 0):

not working as is in chrome 16.0.912.75 m on XP.
IF you give the disabled 'opacity:.2; it changes the opacity of the whole element.
Not sure what effect you are trying to achieve, maybe show some context to help offer a solution.

Comment: I want the arrow and border on the sleect to be opaque, but have a background with opacity, so the colour behind it can show through to some extent. It's adesign requirement. Yeah I've falledn back to opacity on the element, but it's a bit crap that Chrome won't let me use standard css to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem developing a form for a client.  The workaround I ended up using was to set the `background-color` to a lighter version (`#faebe7`) of whatever base I color I wanted to use, in this case red, rather than using `rgba(255,0,0,0.4)`.

Comment: That is only true if your element is on top of white (being translucent makes it lighter). If you have multiple elements on multiple backgrounds, this doesn't work. So it doesn't really answer the question of how to get rgba() colors to behave, since it goes to another color system entirely.